# Using a bucket as a datasource for a droplink/tree field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm trying to enable content editors to select an item that resides in a bucket in a droplink field but I'm unable to find a field type/datasource that enables this.

I need to allow the user to select a single item (so not a multilist), the items are in a bucket as the number of items may be huge and the search api would be most helpful to the editors.

Is there a field or datasource query that will enable a lookup field to select a single bucketed item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a Sitecore multilist with search field.

First you need to set the source of your field to display items within your bucket of a specific template(s).

Example: StartSearchLocation={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}&Filter=+_templatename:sample item

Here is an article describing how to set the source of your field: [Sitecore 7 field types](https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/10/using-the-new-sitecore-7-field-types.aspx)

If you need to limit the selection to one item then you need to also apply some regex. To achieve this you need to enable standards values in the view tab so you can alter the data section.

In the data section add the following regex: ^({[^}]+}\|?){0,1}$ and add some validation text.

Example:
[image]

This article provides additional infromation:[Limit selected items on Sitecore multilist field](http://www.benramey.com/2012/06/12/limit-selected-items-on-sitecore-multilist-field/)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else comes across this as I did, you can also use a query in the source field to filter the items in a droplink.

```
query:/sitecore/content/Home/YourBucket//*[@@templateid='{your-template-guid}']
```

You can also use `@@templatename='Your Template Name'`

Keep in mind that unless your bucketed items aren't numerous (for some reason), the suggested answer is probably better since it provides search, and will not create a massive dropdown list of items.

Answer (score 0):

I made some custom fields for this very purpose: https://github.com/Barsonax/SitecoreSearchFields

It gives you the same rich search interface you normally get when searching in buckets.